# get a number inside a div and count plus one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to get the value(number) inside a div and plus one but if the value is 1 and I am pressing my button it gives me 01 and I want to plus one and if it is 2 and press my button again it gives me 22.

My code is:

```
<div class="mybtn">0</div>

<script>

$(function() {

$(".buttonDown").click(function() 
{
var checkDown = $('.buttonDown').text();
$('.mybtn').hide("fast");
$('.mybtn').text(checkDown+1);
$('.mybtn').fadeIn("slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $(".mybtn").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this).stop(true, true).hide("fast");
        var checkDown = parseInt($.trim($(this).text()), 10);
        $this.text(checkDown + 1).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w33BZ/)

Comment: The `10` refers to the radix, or base, of the parseInt function. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). In this case @Arun is specifying base 10

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding two strings together. Try using the `parseInt()` method around your variable:

```
 $('.mybtn').text(parseInt(checkDown, 10)+1);
```

for best results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+checkDown` instead of simply `checkDown` to implicitly convert string to number.

```
var checkDown = $('.buttonDown').text();
$('.mybtn').text(+checkDown + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing is telling it to concatenate the value to a string, as in "0" + 1 = string "01" instead of converting it to an integer, and then adding one to it.

```
    var checkDown = ParseInt($('.buttonDown').text());
    $('.mybtn').text(checkDown+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<div class="mybtn">0</div>



  <script>

$(function() {

$(".buttonDown").click(function() 
{

var checkDown = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
$(this).hide("fast").text(checkDown+1).fadeIn("slow");


});

});
</script>
```